# Wordpress Lightbox 2 Group images display issue

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I have hit a wall with displaying images in a linked group using WP Lightbox 2.

I've got the plugin activated, and have added the images and linked them as the instructions state (outside characters removed so code will display):

```
<a href="/img/image1.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]><img src="/img/image1.jpg">

<a href="/img/image2.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]><img src="/img/image2.jpg">

<a href="/img/image3.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]><img src="/img/image3.jpg">
```

The issue is that when I click on the first image on the page, it displays in the lightbox but won't allow navigation to the other images. When I start with  the second image, it allows me to navigate to the first image but not the third. To navigate the entire group, I need to start with the last image.

It's almost as if the page is loading in sequence, and if I click on an early image, the page hasn't loaded the whole code to allow recognition that there are later images in the same group.

Please help me, as I'm getting really frustrated with this!

Thanks
Paul